# Subscripts on Variables uneven

Tags: math-mode, best-practices, mathjax

When I write something like

```
$|x_n y_n - xy|<\epsilon$
```

the n's in the subscripts are placed at different depths, which looks awkward in my opinion. For instance, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773546/intuition-behind-proofs) over on MathematicsSE which is where I noticed the problem (although I have run into this several times).

I think it would look best to align the n's, either moving the subscript of "y" up or that of "x" down. Can this be done? And is this considered "good practice" for pure mathematics papers?

Cheers!

Comment: In my opinion, you should use the default way, that is, as you did. Don't change it, let TeX do it for you.

Comment: @MMA: Neither the example in the question nor the formulas in the link have any superscripts and primes.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek But both talked about misalignment of subscripts. Retracted my close vote anyway after seeing your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>Too long for a comment.</sub>

### TeX

The subscript can be lowered, if there is an superscript present. But both the example in the question and the examples in the link do not use superscripts.

In the following example, the subscripts are at the exact vertical position:

```
\documentclass{article}
\showboxdepth=1000    % for \showlists
\showboxbreadth=1000  % for \showlists
\tracingonline=1      % additionally the output of \showlists is shown on the console
\begin{document}
$|x_n y_n - xy|<\epsilon$
\showlists            % shows the boxes of the current main vertical list
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

An excerpt from the `.log` file for `x_n y_n`:

```
\OML/cmm/m/it/10 x
\hbox(3.01389+0.0)x5.44333, shifted 1.49998
.\OML/cmm/m/it/7 n
\OML/cmm/m/it/10 y
\hbox(3.01389+0.0)x5.44333, shifted 1.49998
.\OML/cmm/m/it/7 n
```

Both subscripts are in `\hbox`es, which are shifted below the baseline by the exact same value of `1.49998pt`.

### Mathjax

I think your issue is with [Mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org/), screen shot from the link in the question that uses it for the formula:

> [image: Mathjax]

Comment: Nice! What was it that made the change though? (I'm a total beginner) What do \showboxdepth, \showboxbreadth, \tracingonline do? And if I just copied that into the top of a document, would it drastically affect subscripts on everything? Would that be a bad idea?

Comment: Oh the problem is just Mathjax? So I don't need to change anything?

Comment: @user50612: I do not see, what you could do differently without messing up the formula entirely in the source.

Comment: You are right, it looks fine on my computer. Cheers!

Comment: Indeed, this is a bug in MathJax's HTML-CSS output, which is being fixed in the next release.  See the [issue tracker](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/804) for this problem.